# Inheritance vs. instance

Tags: c++, inheritance, instance

I want to create a class which should be capable of saving various numbers and in addition some other data like for example the name of the data set. For saving the numbers I choose a `std::vector<int>` but now I wonder whether it is better to inherit from it or to make an instance in my class:

```
class MyVector : public std::vector<int> {
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    MyVector (std::string name)
        : std::vector<int>(0), name(name)
    {}
```

versus

```
class MyVector {
private:
    std::string name;

public:
    std::vector<int> data;

    MyVector (std::string name)
        : data(std::vector<int>(0)), name(name)
    {}
```

I'd prefer the first one since I get rid of the extra field `data` and therefore can directly call the built-in methods of `std::vector` without using the intermediary `data`.

Am I right with my idea or is there an essential difference between those two versions?

Comment: Public inheritance has higher coupling (your type is a vector) and has the problem that it isn't safe to delete from a pointer to vector (vector doesn't have a virtual destructor and is not designed to be inherited from.)

Comment: I think making it a vector is misleading and therefore will call for composition as opposed to inheritance. I'd call it `DataSet` since that's what it is. It's also worth pointing out the STL containers don't inherit amongst each other, they have a default template which makes them versatile. `template <class T, class Container = deque<T> > class stack` for example. Something to think about; you're situation could benefit from that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the base class is public, code using a `MyVector` may do anything to it, such as `erase` or `push_back` elements, `std::sort` it, keep iterators to it that it may try to use even after `MyVector` does something to invalidate them etc..

If client code uses some part of the `vector` interface and there's a later change to `MyVector` like deciding it should store data in a `map`, or it mustn't let the client code `clear()` the `vector` without also calling some other function, then all the client code will have to be reviewed and updated correspondingly.  If you're just writing a small program that may not be a significant pain, but if `MyVector` is in a library used by a lot of other people - especially if they're hard to contact, coordinate with or motivate to update their code, then it's extremely undesirable.

If `MyVector`'s reliable operation requires some kind of control over the operations permitted on the data (e.g. it needs to make sure they're always kept sorted, or always lowercase, or there are no duplicates etc.) then granting client code the ability to change the data without `MyVector` being able to intercept and validate those changes is undesirable.

Against that, you as the implementer of `MyVector` get to have it provide a full-featured `std::vector` interface with no effort.

When having `MyVector` as a base you must ensure client code never `delete`s a `MyVector` using a `std::vector<int>*` (which in a case like this would seem extremely unlikely anyway, but for types often stored via base-class pointer it can be a big risk).

Those are the factors to consider - there's no hard right or wrong answer, just experience to guide where to draw the line....

Comment: If I got it right you suggest making `vector<int> data` a private member and write the functions which handle the access I want the user to provide with on my own (which then will refer to the actual `vector` interface).
But if I want to provide the user with full access to the `vector`'s built-in methods (while `MyVector` itself won't change the stored data) and I ensure that base-class pointers are never used then it's perfectly fine to inherit from `vector<int>`?

Comment: @a_guest: if I could summarise everything I'd written down to a paragraph the size of your comment, I would have ;-).  Making `vector` private or a data member gives strong encapsulation, so there's both less exposed functions for the client API to couple to, and the guaranteed chance to intercept function calls and try to satisfy them from whatever new `MyVector` implementation you've moved to.  That's all good.  But, if you're writing a small one-off tool or app and it's very convenient for client code to have full access to the `vector`, then yse - it can work out for the best.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that I'm not running into trouble using the inheritance. Though the actual class is a bit more complex than the example its purpose is acting like a container + storing some additional data and therefore it's not only convenient but required that the client has (almost) full access to all methods of the `vector` interface. Anyway I'll keep your answer in mind if I someday have to write a container class with a different purpose where encapsulation is favourable and/or required.

Comment: @a_guest: sounds about right, though as I'm sure you understand I'd need more inputs to say for sure... e.g. where you are on the "`MyVector` used by a single simple app with no prospect of reuse elsewhere and certainty that a `vector` will continue to be the appropriate container type" through "will be published online for diverse commerical clients to use for business critical systems but we might have to move to a database backend".  It's because there are lots of factors involved that the knee-jerk rule-of-thumb is don't, but that's not always actually the best advice.

Comment: It's rather the first one, this class will be used by a single project (although not small ;-) ) and is not going to be published or used for other projects.